# Python Pandas csv files to Excel worksheets - Cleanup

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

I want to take multiple .csv files and convert them to Excel worksheets in one workbook, specifically using Pandas.

I finally got this to work, but I know the code itself is of poorly written.

Any suggestions on how to clean this up?
"Beautify is better than Ugly"

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl as xl

directory = os.path.join(os.curdir, "data/")
new_xl_file_path = "csv_merge.xlsx"
new_xl_file = xl.Workbook()  # Create a new Excel workbook
new_xl_file.save(new_xl_file_path)
name_list = os.listdir(directory)  # file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, etc...

full_path_list = []  # For reading with pd.read_csv()
data_frame_list = []  # List to save .csv dataframes

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)  # Get full path name
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    data_frame_list.append(df)

counter = 0
with pd.ExcelWriter(new_xl_file_path) as writer:
    for dataframe in data_frame_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=name_list[counter])
        counter += 1
```

Comment: This question would be better suited for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FWIW you should probably combine the two loops. Depending on the size of the files keeping dataframes in memory could become a problem. Also look at `enumerate()` as a way of avoiding your own counter, though I think that a counter for sheetnames probably isn't necessary.